# Memory leaks and dispose

Tags: c#, memory-leaks

May I do not understand the conecept or I do something wrong.
I have some questions about the memory management in .NET.

Imagine the situation:

`Form1` is the big man Form, as MDI-parent and a little `FormChild`, is bound as child:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void simpleButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FormChild formChild = new FormChild();

            formChild.MdiParent = this;
            formChild.Show();

        }
    }
```

Now the child is allocating a little bit memory as simulation:

```
public partial class FormChild : Form
{
    private readonly List<byte[]> _list = new List<byte[]>();

    public FormChild()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


    }

    private void FormChild_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (i < 100)
        {
            _list.Add(new byte[1024 * 1024 * 10]);
            i += 1;
        }

    }

}
```

Now, I'm inspecting with a memory profiler whats going on in the memory heap.
I see, if i click on the button, the memory is allocated. Then I close the `FormChild` and it calls `Dispose()`. But the memory is still allocated. If I click again a `System.OutOfMemoryException` occures.

Why is the GC waiting to free the managed memory?
Or is this my mistake of design?

Comment: Try to reset the MdiParent to null when the child-forms are closed/disposed. It is a reference which might be keeping the childforms within scope.

Comment: Your test is kinda invalid because you create huge arrays that are going to be allocated on the large object heap (LoH). I'd bet my 2cents that you are getting an OutofMemoryException because of managed memory fragmentation.

Comment: The MdiParent is automatically set to null, after `Dispose()`.

Comment: @Jf Beaulac: No, definitely not. I see in my profiler (ANTS memory profiler) there are no issues with large object heap fragmentation.

Comment: Is this the exact code? Because little thing like the scope of formChild  and the place of the while loop matter a lot.

Comment: Surely is this the exact code. Okay, could you tell me how it matters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like some sort of timing problem, where the first instance of formChild  is still reachable (ie not garbage) wen the second one is created. You can't accommodate that `_list` twice.

Note that *I close the FormChild and it calls Dispose()* is a statement about resources and Window handles, not about freeing the memory.

It is not clear if you wrote your own Dispose() but in this (rather special) case you should.

- Cut the `void Dispose(bool disposing)` method from the `FormChild.Designer.cs` file and move it to `FormChild.cs` .
- use it to release the huge memory block:

  ```
  protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
  {
      _list = null;  // add this

      if (disposing && (components != null))
      {
          components.Dispose();
      }
      base.Dispose(disposing);
  }
  ```

Note that this is not a 'usual' form of memory management but it's needed because your _list is unusual too.

Comment: No. I din't (over) write `dispose()` method by my own.

Comment: Then you should, or put `_list = null;` in the FormCosed event.

Comment: Your code works. But I still not understand why my _list should be unusual? Could you tell pls?

Comment: Your list is special because it's so huge. A smaller list would have been recycled eventually, but now the timing is essential. And it's about the GC and reachability, not about Close or (the normal) Dispose. Basically, set `_list = null` as soon as you no longer need it.

Comment: It's really interesting to see how the memory is diffrent with and without `_list = null`. However, it is possible that I have the same problem in my real application. There is a very huge `Datasource` that is loaded and not directly set to null. Could be this recommend to do this?

Comment: Yes, as soon as you're done with it. Restrict it's lifetime and be careful where you store references. If it has a Dispose() then call that first.

Answer (score 6):

The GC only frees memory in response to memory pressure, the main purpose of Dispose is to clean up non-memory related resources.

In other words nulling out managed objects isn't necessarily going to make them get collected any faster, but makes diagnosing memory issues much easier to diagnose.

Comment: Yes, but is the second click on my button to crate a second MDI `FormChild`not enough pressure?

Comment: It depends on how much ram is in the machine. Also, you are working with objects on the large object heap which gets collected less often (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc534993.aspx for more details).

Answer (score 0):

You can for Garbage collection to execute immediately using GC.Collect (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe0c2357.aspx)

However, I typically let it handle itself and implement the Dispose method.

Answer (score -1):

Override `Dispose` in `FormChild` so you can clear up your resources.

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing)
    {
        if (_list != null)
        {
            // Clear it, dispose it, do whatever you want with it.
        }
    }

    base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```

As Yaur said, GC doesn't immediately clean up memory when `Dispose` is called, but it is good practice to clean up what you can.

Comment: This is dealing with managed memory, not unmanaged resources.  It has nothing at all to do with `Dispose`.

Comment: It is a partial answer but I added a theory why it might be helpful. And Dispose() has very little to do with GC