# when i close child form of Static MDI Form , child form don't dispose, but if i create form without static MDI parent , it success dispose. why?

Tags: c#, winforms

when i close child form of Static MDI Form , child form don't clear memory

But if i create form without static MDI parent , it successfully clear memory almost immediately. why?

```
private static Settings _instance;
  public static Settings Instance()
        {
            return _instance ?? (_instance = new Settings());
        }
public Form MdiForm { get; set; }
...
Settings.Instance().MdiForm = Main;
...

var _mainFrm = (frmMain)Settings.Instance().MdiForm;
newForm.MdiParent = _mainFrm;
newForm.Show();
```

Comment: How do you check whenever it is disposed or not? If the original problem is memory leaks, then [related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12482176/1997232).

Comment: I can't tell you why, but maybe  `Dispose();` will help you
Add it into the FormClosing Event or FormClosed

Comment: @LoaStaub    I can see using debug as he goes into the dispose. and using a memory Profiler to look for further results. If the child form was created without static Mdi form , when it is closed, the Profiler shows a decrease in memory to the previous level, and if the child form was created and has mdi parent - static Mdi form, then the memory is not reduced when closing. Memory just hangs somewhere. Even if I download it to 1000 MB, it will not release it.

Comment: @Sinatr I can see using debug as he goes into the dispose. and using a memory Profiler to look for further results. If the child form was created without static Mdi form , when it is closed, the Profiler shows a decrease in memory to the previous level, and if the child form was created and has mdi parent - static Mdi form, then the memory is not reduced when closing. Memory just hangs somewhere. Even if I download it to 1000 MB, it will not release it

Comment: I think you need to release the Instance,
so delete all linkings to it.
Maybe set your instance `null` and the Garbage Collector will release it?

Comment: @LoaStaub I can't do that. there are a lot of child forms on this Instance.MdiForm